# Free remote desktop from laptop with proxy or tablet without admin access

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-10, remote-access, remote-desktop

I have a desktop computer at home which I want to control from my workplace sometimes.

In my work I have a laptop that has admin access but has a company proxy, and I have a tablet that doesn't have a proxy nor admin access.

I need a free remote desktop software that works with Windows 10 to connect from either the latop or the tablet.

It should work so that I can leave the computer at home turned on with the software without anyone there to help while I go work and then connect to it at any time of the day. Also, do I need to make it so it doesn't go into sleep/suspend mode?

Something easy to setup and use is nice but if you have more than one suggestion let me know which one you believe better suits my needs and the other alternatives as backup plan.

Comment: Do you know, can or want to do a port-forwarding on your home computer? That would enable the built-in remote desktop server to run on your home computer, assuming you have at least a Professional Windows edition.

Comment: @Alejandro I never heared of port-forwarding. The Tablet has the Home version, while the latop and the desktop computer have the Professional version. I would probably need some help to set that up as I usually have bad experiences with generic online tutorials, getting stuck at some part or just not knowing what's wrong at all.

Comment: It looks like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) might do it. Only tested it between the laptop and the tablet so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have found the answer yourself, but I will suggest you're looking for installing [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/) on the home machine, and TeamViewer Portable on the laptop/tablet. The portable allows you to not need Admin rights to install software.

There are two options for remoting back to the home machine, with user consent, and with a password to bypass user consent. You would need the latter. I have used this several times to help out friends. If the machine is on, you can connect to it. If it is off (power outage, connection outage, etc.), the system will show as offline in TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Remote Desktop https://remotedesktop.google.com
√ Allows device to give and/or receive remote control
√ Free
√ Works with Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/) it's free for private use, but you would need to buy a commercial license (just like with TeamViewer)